# Laptop Graphics Card making noises and vibrating, is there a way to fix it?

Tags: laptop, graphics-card, noise

I am the owner of a Samsung NP355v, with a Raedon 7660G graphics card. Recently, it has started to make a weird noise (as if the fan was forced) and vibrating, and I fear I won't be able to use my computer in fear that it will stop working soon. So, is there a protocol to proceed in cases like these to try to fix the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the fan bearing is busted. It's bad, but not a showstopper, as you can probably find a replacement fan on [aliexpress](http://aliexpress.com). Alternatively, this is a warranty issue, if it's relatively new.

First, contact the reseller about their RMA procedure for this. If they somehow manage to get away without doing something about it, or if they want to overchange you, you can probably find a replacement fan for a fraction of the cost online.

Comment: Also, check for a dust lump on the fan, throwing off balance. Try cleaning before replacing.

Comment: Is there a way to replace a fan bearing from a graphics card?

Comment: @BioFalcon Yes, but it's easier (and usually cheaper) to just replace the fan.

Comment: @Jarmund thanks for the advice, I tried cleaning it but didn't work, I will now replace the fan